# Selenium - how to switch to a different (login) window that is brought up?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

My application has an admin account and the testing has been within that.

This account then has hyperlinks for 'regular' users that they use for their login, for example:

One   `http://dmplanning-stage.herokuapp.com/p/7Fimn1FRs1WZe5xmFTUA`
Two   `http://dmplanning-stage.herokuapp.com/p/FRs1WZe7Fimn15TUAxmF`
Three `http://dmplanning-stage.herokuapp.com/p/mFTUA7Fimn1FRs1WZe5x`

These links are generated each time I run the test suite and the id's are different.

I've created a test to locate and click on the hyperlink on a page that lists these users and their login hyperlinks.  The test runs and selenium makes the browser bring up the new window but how do I then switch to it, so I can login and continue?

To make it more challenging the other window has an empty title, i.e.

I can get the programmer to add a title but it would take time.  Is there any way with/without that to identify and switch to the other window?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using Selenium IDE. So from the [Selenium Reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html)

---

> **selectPopUp ( windowID )**
>
> Simplifies the process of selecting a popup
>   window (and does not offer functionality beyond what selectWindow()
>   already provides).
>
> - If windowID is either not specified, or specified
>     as "null", the first non-top window is selected. The top window is the
>     one that would be selected by selectWindow() without providing a
>     windowID . This should not be used when more than one popup window is
>     in play.
> - Otherwise, the window will be looked up considering windowID
>     as the following in order: 1) the "name" of the window, as specified
>     to window.open(); 2) a javascript variable which is a reference to a
>     window; and 3) the title of the window. This is the same ordered
>     lookup performed by selectWindow .

---

> **selectWindow ( windowID )**
>
> Selects a popup window using a window
>   locator; once a popup window has been selected, all commands go to
>   that window. To select the main window again, use null as the target.
>   Window locators provide different ways of specifying the window
>   object: by title, by internal JavaScript "name," or by JavaScript
>   variable.
>
> - **title**=*My Special Window*: Finds the window using the text that appears
>     in the title bar. Be careful; two windows can share the same title. If
>     that happens, this locator will just pick one.
> - **name**=*myWindow*: Finds
>     the window using its internal JavaScript "name" property. This is the
>     second parameter "windowName" passed to the JavaScript method
>     window.open(url, windowName, windowFeatures, replaceFlag) (which
>     Selenium intercepts).
> - **var**=*variableName*: Some pop-up windows are
>     unnamed (anonymous), but are associated with a JavaScript variable
>     name in the current application window, e.g. "window.foo =
>     window.open(url);". In those cases, you can open the window using
>     "var=foo".

**`selectWindow`** would be ideal if you can retrieve the name of the new window that is opened.

> If you're having trouble figuring out the name of a window that you
>   want to manipulate, look at the Selenium log messages which identify
>   the names of windows created via window.open (and therefore
>   intercepted by Selenium). You will see messages like the following for
>   each window as it is opened:
>
> > `debug: window.open call intercepted; window ID (which you can use with
> >     selectWindow()) is "myNewWindow"`
>
> In some cases, Selenium will be unable to intercept a call to
>   window.open (if the call occurs during or before the "onLoad" event,
>   for example). (This is bug SEL-339.) In those cases, you can force
>   Selenium to notice the open window's name by using the Selenium
>   openWindow command, using an empty (blank) url, like this:
>   openWindow("", "myFunnyWindow").

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windowhandle to switch to the new window.
Something sort of..

```
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get  // Go to ur login page
driver.click //Click on link which launches new window
Set<String> s = driver.getwindowhandles() //this will return all open windows
driver.switchTo.window(s[1]);  //will switch to second window
```

Hope it helps..