# Pick a date from a calendar in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I need to pick a date from a calendar in Selenium. When I click on the `Calendar` button a new window opens up with the calendar.

There is a 'Today' button on the calendar that I need to click on. But there is no iframe or window ID where I could switch to.

I am getting the *No Such Element Exception* error.

How can I do that?

Comment: The answers on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750948/selenium-how-to-switch-to-a-different-login-window-that-is-brought-up might be able to help you

Comment: can you post a picture of that popup? is it java script or html?

Comment: I have added the picture. Please check now. @Dude

Comment: Hard to tell from the screenshot, but that calendar is probably not in a separate window or frame.  The problem is probably either timing (selenium tries to click the button before the calendar appears) or your selector is incorrect.  Try posting your Java code and the html of the Today button.

Comment: Its not the timing issue. I have added wait and i can see the calender opening before Selenium tries clicking on the Today button. The Java code for today button is 

'driver.findElement(By.id("button-1010-btnIconEl")).click();'

I think the problem is that it doesn't shift to Calender. The calender has no frame id or window id i can switch to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor =(JavaScriptExecutor) driver;

 jsExecutor.executeScript("$(\"#datepicker\").val('02.05.2015')");
```

Inspect the datepicker/caledner field and get the relevant locator attribute

You can also use Jquery Xpath with $x instead of $

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed. I would like to add that I also needed to set the value of the hidden input _submit of the date field. executor.executeScript("$(\"input[name=datefield_submit]\").val('2018/12/17')");

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed! Used windows handlers to switch to the new window. Thanks all.